# Installing PyOpenNI in Windows - Boost_python issue

Tags: python, boost

I am trying to install PyOpenNI, following the instruction in:

https://github.com/jmendeth/PyOpenNI/wiki/Building-on-Windows

I installed the dependencies:

- CMake
- Git
- Python
- The Boost set of C++ libraries

But when I type:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ..\PyOpenNI
```

I get the following error:

```
The following Boost libraries could not be found:

      boost_python

No Boost libraries were found. You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
Boost.
```

I have Python 2.7 installed and it should be in my PATH. I added the variables:

```
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\boost
BOOST_ROOT = C:\Program Files (x86)\boost
BOOSTROOT = C:\Program Files (x86)\boost
```

But I keep getting the issues.

What am I missing?

Thank you.